# Como remover o ícone pequeno no onesignal?

Tags: android, api

Galera fiz uma pergunta aqui mais cedo mas disseram que não ficou claro.

Eu quero remover o ícone pequeno da notificação do *OneSignal* para *Android*.

Olha: [image: Imagem dos ícones]

Na notificação aparece 2 ícones e eu queria remover esse pequeno que fica ao lado, alguém pode ajudar? Uso o Android Studio.

Comment: Quando você envia a mensagem, você está definindo a propriedade [small icon](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons#section-set-default-small-icon-and-accent-colors)?

Comment: Não, devo definir ?

Comment: Ele é definido automaticamente em dispositivos API 21+  https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons#section-about-notification-icons